# Prevent Radeon driver from attaching to specific PCI devices?

Tags: linux, debian, amd-radeon, linux-kvm, debian-wheezy

I have two Radeon cards in this machine, a [Radeon HD 6570](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_Series#Radeon_HD_6500.2F6600) and a [Radeon HD 6950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_Series#Radeon_HD_6900):

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Turks [Radeon HD 6570] 
>   02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]

I'm trying to get VGA passthrough to work with [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) on [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Wheezy), passing through the 6950 as a secondary video card to a Windows 7 guest. This works fine if I blacklist the `radeon` kernel module via `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

If I remove the blacklist to run X11 (or even just a [KMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager#Kernel_Mode_Setting) console) on the 6570 the `radeon` module seems to attach to *both* cards:

dmesg | egrep "01:00.0|02:00.0|radeon"

> pci 0000:01:00.0: [1002:6759] type 0 class 0x000300 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff 64bit pref] 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0xf7e20000-0xf7e3ffff 64bit] 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 20: [io  0xe000-0xe0ff] 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 30: [mem 0xf7e00000-0xf7e1ffff pref] 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: [1002:6719] type 0 class 0x000300 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xd0000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref] 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0xf7d20000-0xf7d3ffff 64bit] 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 20: [io  0xd000-0xd0ff] 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 30: [mem 0xf7d00000-0xf7d1ffff pref] 
>   pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2 
>   vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:01:00.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none 
>   vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:02:00.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=none,locks=none 
>   vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:02:00.0 
>   vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:01:00.0 
>   pci 0000:01:00.0: Boot video device 
>   [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled. 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used) 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF 
>   [drm] radeon: 1024M of VRAM memory ready 
>   [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready. 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI. 
>   [drm] radeon: irq initialized. 
>   radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled 
>   [drm] radeon: ib pool ready. 
>   [drm] radeon: power management initialized 
>   fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device 
>   fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device 
>   [drm] Initialized radeon 2.12.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003) 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used) 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x000000009FFFFFFF 
>   [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready 
>   [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready. 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: radeon: using MSI. 
>   [drm] radeon: irq initialized. 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: WB enabled 
>   [drm] radeon: ib pool ready. 
>   [drm] radeon: power management initialized 
>   fb1: radeondrmfb frame buffer device 
>   [drm] Initialized radeon 2.12.0 20080528 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 1 
>   [drm] radeon: finishing device. 
>   radeon 0000:02:00.0: ffff88041a941800 unpin not necessary 
>   [drm] radeon: ttm finalized 
>   pci-stub 0000:02:00.0: claimed by stub 
>   pci-stub 0000:02:00.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X

This causes the Windows 7 VM to bluescreen on boot.

How can I configure things so that module `radeon` only attaches to the 6570 and not the 6950?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had had some [`pci_stub`-related lines](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM) in my `rc.local` but this was apparently too late in the boot process to help, running after `radeon` started fiddling with things.

I fixed things by moving the `pci_stub` kernel module stuff to the `initramfs`:

1. `lspci -nn | grep Cayman` to find the `vendor:device` numbers (at the very end of the line) for the 6950 and its HDMI port:

   ```
   02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950] [1002:6719]
   02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6900 Series] [1002:aa80]
   ```
2. Pop open `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add a new line:

   ```
   pci_stub ids=1002:6719,1002:aa80
   ```
3. Rebuild the `initramfs`:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
4. Reboot and observe `pci_stub` beating out `radeon`:

   ```
   dmesg | egrep "pci-stub|radeon"

   pci-stub: add 1002:6719 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
   pci-stub 0000:02:00.0: claimed by stub
   pci-stub: add 1002:AA80 sub=FFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFF cls=00000000/00000000
   pci-stub 0000:02:00.1: claimed by stub
   [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
   radeon 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
   radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF (1024M used)
   radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000040000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
   ```
5. Enjoy bluescreen-free VGA passthrough!

Comment: The above didn't work for me. Instead I added `pci_stub.ids=1002:6719,1002:aa80` to end of the kernel command line in grub config file. I suspect the reason is that `pci-stub` module is built into the kernel in my setup.

Comment: Referenced in *[Multiheaded NVIDIA Gaming using Ubuntu 14.04 + KVM](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/)* (step 2).

Answer (score 5):

Using genpfault answer as reference, I created another answer, I think is more simple.

The first step is the same as above:

Then I created a file called /lib/modprobe.d/pci-stub.conf, whith the args I found:

```
options pci-stub ids=1002:9715,1002:970f
```

Then I created a file called /lib/modprobe.d/drm.conf, with softdep:

```
softdep drm pre: pci-stub
```

This way, when the boot process tries to load drm, first loads pci-stub, which reserves the hardware of one video card, and prevents drm to attach to some device.

Later you can remove the reservation in rc.local, `modprobe -r pci-stub`.

Optionally you can load another module `modprobe another-module` for that card.